# Why are objects not considered a type of data structure?

Tags: c++, object, data-structures

Recently I just started learning data structures and algorithm and I've been wondering why arrays is a type of data structure, but objects are not. Since we know an object would hold data and then have functionalities to manipulate them just like a an array. I've googled this, but I haven't found an answer. I'll appreciate if anyone can explain this.
Here is a question related to mine, hope this clarifies my question more https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/pmv63n/why_is_an_object_not_a_data_structure/

You can see more on the type of data structures here
https://www.google.com/amp/s/searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/data-structure%3famp=1

Comment: what makes you think that objects *aren't* a type of data structure in all of those scenarios? there's a huge [citation-needed], that would need to be language-by-language

Comment: where did you read that? Afaik "data structure" is not a formal C++ term.

Comment: I think you're getting hung up on a term. When "data structures" are studied it usually means "generic" data structures: arrays, linked lists, trees, hash tables, etc. An object is a language-/implementation-specific data structure.

Comment: An array is an object (at least in C++ terms) so the question  is predicated on a contradiction.

Comment: this can only be answered / clarified if you add the source of this statement. The thing is, arrays are objects, hence it doesnt make sense to say "arrays are data structures, but objects are not"

Comment: I don't see where that link says that objects are not data structures, especially in a C++ sense. Are you talking about the lack of an Object bullet in the "Types of data structures" non-exhaustive list?

Comment: The `c++` tag makes this question particularly confusing . in C++, "object" has a *very* specific meaning which is a little different that what it normally implies in language-agnostic OOP literature. A single `int` or a pointer are as much objects as polymorphic instances of deep class hierarchies,

Comment: From your link: "_For instance, in an object-oriented programming language, the data structure and its associated methods are bound together as part of a class definition._" - I assume that you mean that instances of these data structures aren't data structures? I could buy that reasoning even though it feels awkward.

Comment: Here is a question similar to mine, hope this clarifies my question more https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/pmv63n/why_is_an_object_not_a_data_structure/

Comment: @MustaphaAhmedYusuf: Clarifications should be part of the question, not links to external resources.

Comment: You need to clarify with whoever told you "objects aren't data structures" what they mean by "objects". They might be wrong, misleadingly pedantic, or vacuously correct. *Some* objects are instances of a data structure, e.g. all array objects are instances of the Array data structure, and all `std::queue` objects are instances of the Queue data structure.

Comment: The link you hope clarifies the question leads to a similar question, one that is not really any clearer. Also, the responses to the linked question comprise another discussion of how the question is based upon flawed premises. So, no, it does not clarify anything. What your question (and the linked question) needs is a reference supporting your dubious claim "objects are not [data structures]".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that Data Structure is actually defined for C++, but here is how I would distinguish, if I understand your question correctly.

An array is a type of container which holds data.  An instance of an array is
an object, which is a specific use of the array data structure.

```cpp
// Instantiation of a vector object - the object itself is not a 'data structure' it is a specific use of a data structure
std::vector <int> x = {1, 2, 3};

// The data structure itself is just std::vector
```